# Google Sheets Script Editor: not sending my email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set up a script that notifies me when a certain value in my script changes from 'Nee' to 'Ja'. I am not very familiar with this language so maybe it's an easy solution but I've been trying for a number of days in a row but can't get it to work. Hoping for your help.

Here's the code I created. It's a sheet with about 25 rows that each have this 'Nee' or 'Ja' value in column 11 of each row. The code below is what I use for checking row 5.

```
function triggerNotification5() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Index');
  var notevalue5 = sheet.getRange(5, 11).getValue();

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();  
  scriptProperties.setProperty('notifycheck5', notevalue5);
  var notifyValue5 = scriptProperties.getProperty('notifycheck5');

  if (notifyValue5 == 'Ja') {
    var email = sheet.getRange(5, 9).getValue();
    var stockname = sheet.getRange(5, 3).getValue();
    var companystatus = sheet.getRange(5, 10).getValue();      
    sendMarksEmail(email, stockname, companystatus);     
  }
}
```

It refers to the function sendMarksEmail in the end. That's looking like this:

```
function sendMarksEmail(email,stockname,companystatus) {
  var subject = "Aandeel Alert: " + stockname + " (dit is een " + companystatus + ")";
  var message = "De recente prijs van het aandeel " 
  + stockname + " wijkt meer af dan de gewenste notificatiemarge van de 
  wijziging van de AEX ten opzichte van gisteren. Dit is voor jou een " + 
  companystatus + ". Mogelijk is er iets aan de hand.";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace your `if (notifyValue5 == 'Ja') ` with `if (notifyValue5 === 'Ja') `

Comment: What is the purpose of using script properties? currently it just seems like you do `value → variable → property → value → if statement` Instead it could be `if (notevalue5 == 'Ja'`. Also, keep in mind that this is case sensitive. What does the execution transcript say? Have you tried running through the debugger and watching what values you get?

Comment: Hi Vyautas,

I read somewhere that if I read the actual value of column 11 (which is a formula that decides to say 'Nee' or 'Ja'), the script will read the formula instead of the outcome of the formula. That could be fixed by making it a property. That's why. I just tried checking the cell directly as you suggest but it didn't work either, sad enough. Many thanks for your time and help though!

Comment: What about the execution transcript and debugging? Are you getting through the `if` statement to the function? Once you get to the `sendMarksEmail` function are `email`, `subject` and `message` all string types?

Comment: Hi Darpan,

I tried your suggestion but without success :-( Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Hi Vyautas,

Thanks for your second reply. To be honest I am not quite sure what you mean. By putting ' and ' around the 'Ja' it is seen as a text value right? I also get no errors when I run the debug functionality of the Script editor. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi again Vyautas, I tried once more. And I see that the three variables you are mentioning are indeed set to 'unknown' if I debug the sendMarksEmail function instead of the triggerNotification5. So you're probably right. Any idea how I should set those to String?

Comment: You can set your break point at the very start of function `triggerNotification5`. As you press F8, you should end up inside of `sendMarksEmail`. If you debug that function directly, you will have no variables passed to it. Right now the question is wether you actually end up running `sendMarksEmail` in the first place or if your script simply gets to the `if` statement, sees that the condition is not meat and skips whatever is under it.

Comment: Hi Vytautas. At first my apologies as I missed a 't' in your name when mentioning you before. I am working on a Mac so I am unable to F8. However, I switched the 'Ja' to 'Nee' and ran the function again and I did not get an email either. Which means your suggestion of getting to the if-statement, seeing the condition is not met and skips whatever is under it does not apply. I tried it with both == and === to retry Darpan's earlier suggestion as well.

Comment: Hi Vytautas, I tried again but now I did the != 'Ja' instead of == 'Ja'  and I did actually receive an email. So it's indeed the value of the cell that's being read incorrectly, it does not recognize the 'Ja'.

Comment: Consider using `console.log(notevalue5)` after you read it from the sheet in your first function. This will send the log to Stackdriver, where you can view it easily, unlike the logs from `Logger.log()`. To view, go to menu **View -> Stackdriver Logging**.

Comment: Hi tehhowxh,

Thank you for your time and help. If I check the Stackdriver Logging it returns "#REF!". I am not sure what it means, but it's probably not what we want ;-) Do you have any clue?

Comment: `#REF` is not a Javascript / Google Apps Script error. Thus, the cell whose value you accessed, has the value `#REF`. `#REF` generally occurs when a spreadsheet formula refers to non-existent ranges. Please verify that you are reading the proper cells in your project: `sheet.getRange("D1")` is the same as `sheet.getRange(1, 4)`.

Comment: Hi tehhowch, I've made the changes you suggested and am now pointing to "K5" instead of 5,11. I can also confirm that the value in cell K5 returns 'Ja' or 'Nee'. However I still get the #REF! logging. Could it be the problem that I am performing that IF statement on a cell that has a formula in it instead of a plain text value? Or maybe I am not pointing to the spreadsheet correctly?

Comment: I have never had any problem with getValue() reading values of formula cells. In instances where internal sheet shenanigans were messing with getValue() using range.getDisplayValue() resolved them. It is largely for formatting/rounding dependencies but might be worth a try

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jared. Unfortunately I still end up getting #REF! in the Stackdriver Logging and it's driving me mad ;-) The script is not understanding what is written inside that K5 cell. I will keep on trying though, can't be far from a solution I think.

Comment: Add the formula that you are using to set the value of K5.

Comment: Hi @Rubén,

Thanks for your reply. I have now added your suggestion to the code, which now adds the formula in K5 and then tries to read it, but still it gets #REF! as the outcome of the value I am logging. It is now looking like this:

=====

function triggerNotification5() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Index");
    var cell = sheet.getRange("K5");
    cell.setFormula('=IF(OR(G5>=L5,G5<-L5), "Ja", "Nee")');
    var notevalue5 = cell.getDisplayValue();
    console.log(notevalue5);  etc...

=====

Comment: @ all many thanks for your time and help. I managed to fix the issue. By copying the contentsOnly version of the formula cell to a new cell and perform the IF on that new cell it works fine.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('Index!K5');
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Index!M5'), {contentsOnly: true});
  var notevalue = ss.getRange("Index!M5").getValue();
  console.log(notevalue);